# Is there a modern community to share knowledge and best-practicies of those who work with SuiteScript 2.0?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitecloud

I'm fairly new to `NetSuite` and `SuiteScript 2.0` in particular. I have already developed several applications and what I found out is that there is almost nothing I can find on the internet about `SuiteScript`. I mean if you use `React` or `Vue` or other popular frameworks, you can easily google for issues you have and most likely you will find several answers, which is definitely cool.

There is `NetSuite Help Center` - some sort of `API` documentation which I use all the time. There is a Suite Answers, where you can find help from `NetSuite` Support. But those are just internal resources with its pros and cons. As I've mentioned earlier, I did try to find additional resources on the web where people share their experience (best practicies etc.), but unfortunately didn't found anything. Even here, on `stackoverflow`, not so many people are into `SuiteScript`.

Those who worked with `NetSuite` for a while, please share some info where to find on-demand help.

Comment: There is a NetSuite user group at Oracle that can help: https://community.oracle.com/community/netsuite

Comment: @ChrisWhite, already joined that, thanks. However, 17 questions total, most of which were asked 3+ years ago. It seems this place is abandoned.

Comment: Hmm. That sucks. They recently moved it to Oracle, I bet they didn't move everything over (yet?). Don't currently have an account there so I wasn't aware, but will need one soon, so that's crappy news. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the NetSuite Professionals Slack group. It is free, and there are over 4000 members. https://www.netsuiteprofessionals.com

Comment: +1, I have gone to the Slack community for help several times now and always receive great help and advice.